# Square submatrix with sum equal to k

Tags: matrix, dynamic-programming

Given a 2D matrix of numbers and a number K, find if there exists a **square submatrix** with **sum equal to K**.

I have tried the DP approach with TC O(n^3) and optimised it using binary search to get TC O (n log n).

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-square-sub-matrix-with-sum-less-than-or-equals-to-k/

Is there a way to do this is **O(n*n)** ?

Answer (score 0):

I saw a similar question on the coding challenges site [CSES](https://cses.fi/problemset/) (If ill find the question link I will attach it here).

I won't give you the answer but a general direction, try to research about `prefixes sum array`.

here is a [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prefix-sum-array-implementation-applications-competitive-programming/#:%7E:text=Prefix%20Sum%20Array%20%E2%80%93%20Implementation%20and%20Applications%20in%20Competitive%20Programming,-Difficulty%20Level%20%3A%20Medium&text=Given%20an%20array%20arr%5B%5D,arr%5Bi%5D.) to an explanation and use.

You can use this concept to solve this problem in O(n^2) time and O(n^2) space complexity.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I am familiar with the concept of prefix sum array, but don't really understand how I can use it and ensure that the sub matrix is a square. Won't that require another loop ?

Comment: If the coordinates in the matrix are given, checking if they are creating a square is O(1) time

Comment: There are n^2 points, so checking each of them will be O(n^4). And if I go along the diagonal for each point, that will still be O(n^3). I am not able to understand your approach. Can you elaborate more or provide the link for the cses question you mentioned?